# Rounding error for datetimes when saving + reading an Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, datetime

When saving a dataframe with datetimes to an Excel file, and reading it back, rounding error makes `datetime` equality tests wrong:

```
import pandas as pd, datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2],     
                   'B': [datetime.datetime(2010,1,1,0,0,0), datetime.datetime(2013,9,10,11,13,55)]})
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')                # save to Excel file
df2 = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')        # load to Excel file
print(df2)
S1 = {df2.loc[df['A'] == 1, 'B'].iat[0], datetime.datetime(2010,1,1,0,0,0)}
S2 = {df2.loc[df['A'] == 2, 'B'].iat[0], datetime.datetime(2013,9,10,11,13,55)}
print(S1)  # one single element, as expected
print(S2)  # two elements because of rounding errors
```

Here the set `S2` should contain one single element since the two dates in it are identical.

How to prevent this problem to happen?

---

Indeed, this is how the dataframe is read from the Excel file:

```
   Unnamed: 0  A                          B
0           0  1 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000000
1           1  2 2013-09-10 11:13:54.999999
```

NB: I have pandas version 1.2.0, Python 3.7.6 (64 bit), Windows.

Linked to: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/62977/pandas-datetime-error-when-reading-from-excel-file

Comment: Not replicated on my system (Python 3.7, Pandas 1.1.4). Also, I would recommend using Pandas' datetime instead of Python's datetime.

Comment: @QuangHoang I edited and added the version I have in my question. In fact in my real code, I don't create any datetime, they are all read from Excel files (with `read_excel`). Then, how would you use Pandas' datetime?

Comment: Since you read data directly from excel file, it's almost certainly is already Pandas datetime. I can't say anything further because that's not replicated on my system. You can try mitigate the problem with rounding: `df['B'] = df['B'].dt.floor('S')` , but not sure if it's what you want.

Comment: @QuangHoang Can we automatically round all datetimes for all columns (without specifying them one by one) by doing something like `read_excel(parse_dates=..., round_dates=...)` ?

Comment: `date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).dt.normalize()` maybe?

Comment: I tried with `df2 = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).dt.floor('S'), parse_dates=True)`, with and without `parse_dates=True`, and with your previous comment with `date_parser` and `normalize` @QuangHoang, but none of them worked. It's always parsed as `2013-09-10 11:13:54.999999`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally solved it:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].dt.round(freq='s')
```